# Python: Cannot find and install python module 'video'

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, pip, python-module

I am using Python 3.6. I tried to run the OpenCV optical flow code:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/opt_flow.py

and there was an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'video'
```

I thought the 'video' module must be missing. So, I run

```
pip install video
```

in the command line, but it gave me this error:

```
Collecting video
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement video (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for video
```

Could anyone advise on how to solve this problem? How to find where are the OpenCV modules installed in local drive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add [video.py](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/video.py), to your project. It not a package that you need to install rather its a module which exist in the same repo.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I did exactly that, and now I got another error:

`from tst_scene_render import TestSceneRender
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tst_scene_render'`

This is from these code in video.py:

`# local modules
from tst_scene_render import TestSceneRender
import common`

I think I built the repo incorrectly. Could you help show me how to do it right? I am using Ecliopse IDE by the way.

Comment: Add `https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/tst_scene_render.py` to your project

Comment: I did, and it finally worked! Thank you very much for your help! :-)

Just wondering, though, if we should always add files manually like this when running the OpenCV python code, or is there a way to setup the repo such that this is always taken care of?

Comment: Hi @PL01 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi @Surajano, answer accepted!

Can you help me with the question on linking / setting up the repo that I posted in my earlier comment? Thx!

Comment: Hey @PL01, You can clone the project, or install via pip to avoid this. After that you can import the modules that you want in your project